# PySpark transform multiple columns into a single column complex json

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a flat input dataframes object with the following columns:

```
col_a: string
col_b: string
col_c: int
col_d: boolean
```

I want to transform and load this into an output file. I want my output file to be rows of json. The structure of each json *row* is as follows (indented to make it easy to read, but when it's stored it should just be 1 line):

```
{
  "result": [
     {
         "pair": [
           {
              "a": {col_a}
              "b": {col_b}
              ...
           },
           {
               "c": {col_c}
               "d": {col_d}
           }
         ]
     }
  ]
}
```

When these json rows are stored, they should look like:

```
{ "result": [{ "pair" ... }]} \n
{ "result": [{ "pair" ... }]}\n
```

Each json row object is sufficiently complex. What's the best way to implement transform + load for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express the required nested structure against the flat columns. Note that all elements in array must have the same structure.

```
_data = [
    ('val_a', 'val_b', 42, True),
    ('val_a', 'val_b', 43, False),
]
_schema = ['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c', 'col_d']
df = spark.createDataFrame(_data, _schema)

pair = F.struct(
    F.col('col_a').alias('a'),
    F.col('col_b').alias('b'),
    F.col('col_c').alias('c'),
    F.col('col_d').alias('d')
)
pair = F.struct(F.array(pair, pair).alias('pair'))
result = F.array(pair).alias('result')

tdf = df.select(result)
tdf.write.format('json').save('<some-location>')
```